# When is the symplectic reduction of an action reduced?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, group-actions

Let $X$ be a smooth affine variety with an action of a reductive linear algebraic group $G$ over the complex numbers. We have a moment map $\mu:T^*(X)\to \mathfrak{g}^*$ given by $\mu(x,\xi,Y)=\xi(\tilde{Y}_x)$ where $\tilde{Y}$ is the vector field on $X$ obtained by applying the differential of the action map $a:G\times X\to X$ to $Y\in T_xX\subseteq  T_{(e,x)}G\times X$. 
The (affine) symmplectic reduction of $X$ by the action of $G$ is given by the categorical quotient of the fiber of the moment map $\mu^{-1}(0)$ by the induced action of $G$..

Note that in this question I consider the *schematic* fiber of the moment map, which might in principle be non-reduced.

**Question**: Is there a classification the linear representations of $G$ for which the symplectic reduction of the action of $G$ on the representation space is reduced?